# PHP & Jquery Ajax, json, get data in the ajax destination file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to send an array in php trough ajax to a different server, so I am trying the following.

Array already encoded with `json_encode`:

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"AVOCADO TOAST TARTINE","qty":"1","price":"88.00","spec":""},
  {"id":"16","name":"ADD BERRIES","qty":"1","price":"48.00","spec":""}
]
```

so in the origin file I have:

```
<script>
var cart = <?php echo $cart; ?>; //this is the array above
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.mydestinationurl.com.hk/new/admin/do_lpq_order.php',
            crossDomain: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: cart
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
</script>
```

And in the destination file I have this:

```
<?PHP
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://localhost': case 'https://localhost': 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    break;
}

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

But when I see the log to check the data I sent I get:

```
Array
(
    [AVOCADO_TOAST_TARTINE] => 
    [ADD_BERRIES] => 
)
```

Is like I have lost lot of information.
So how can I get the total `json array` to use in php?

Comment: Dont pass array, convert array to string and pass it and when you get it on server side convert string to array using json_decode

Comment: yo mean removing the [] right? let me try

Comment: no dont need to remove this but pass as string

Comment: yeah, I have used JSON.stringify and now I get the full result!! thanks

Comment: Glad i help you! welcome